# How to use validation when i use duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, duplicates

When I Use duplicate key update

```
INSERT INTO test_table (name, age, date) 
       VALUES (Kevin, 20, now)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name),
                               age = VALUES(age),
                               date = VALUES(date)
```

I want to compare with existing value for validation
How can I do?

I have tried some method

```
where date < VALUES(date)
```

But all of method are syntax error

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
INSERT INTO test_table (name, age, date) 
       VALUES (Kevin, 20, now)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY 
       UPDATE name = CASE WHEN `date`< values(`date`) THEN VALUES(name) ELSE name end,
              age= CASE WHEN `date`< values(`date`) THEN VALUES(age) ELSE age end,
              `date`= CASE WHEN `date`< values(`date`) THEN VALUES(date) ELSE `date` end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO test_table (name, age, date) 
       VALUES (Kevin, 20, now)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE age =  IF(`date` < values(`date`), values(age), age),
                               name = IF(`date` < values(`date`), values(name), name),
                               date = IF(`date` < values(`date`), values(date), date)
```